# How do I use the MouseWheel event to scroll through the TabItems of nested TabControls?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, tabcontrol, mousewheel

I have a TabControl that can contain a TabControl in each TabItem. There is the xaml-code:

```
<TabControl  Height="300" Width="500" MouseWheel="TabControl_MouseWheel">
       <TabItem Header="1" Width="50">
            <TabControl MouseWheel="TabControl_MouseWheel">
                <TabItem Header="1" Width="50"></TabItem>
                <TabItem Header="2" Width="50"></TabItem>
                <TabItem Header="3" Width="50"></TabItem>
                <TabItem Header="4" Width="50"></TabItem>
                <TabItem Header="5" Width="50"></TabItem>
                <TabItem Header="6" Width="50"></TabItem>
                <TabItem Header="7" Width="50"></TabItem>
                <TabItem Header="8" Width="50"></TabItem>
                <TabItem Header="9" Width="50"></TabItem>
            </TabControl>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="2" Width="50">
            <TabControl MouseWheel="TabControl_MouseWheel">
                <TabItem Header="1" Width="50"></TabItem>
                <TabItem Header="2" Width="50"></TabItem>
                <TabItem Header="3" Width="50"></TabItem>
                <TabItem Header="4" Width="50"></TabItem>
                <TabItem Header="5" Width="50"></TabItem>
                <TabItem Header="6" Width="50"></TabItem>
                <TabItem Header="7" Width="50"></TabItem>
                <TabItem Header="8" Width="50"></TabItem>
                <TabItem Header="9" Width="50"></TabItem>
            </TabControl>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="3" Width="50"></TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="4" Width="50"></TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="5" Width="50"></TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="6" Width="50"></TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="7" Width="50"></TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="8" Width="50"></TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="9" Width="50"></TabItem>
    </TabControl>
```

I want to change the selected item of tabcontrols by mouse wheeling. There is MouseWheel event handler:

```
private void TabControl_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        TabControl tabControl = sender as TabControl;
        if (tabControl != null)
        {
            if (e.Delta < 0)
            {
                if (tabControl.SelectedIndex + 1 < tabControl.Items.Count)
                    tabControl.SelectedItem = tabControl.Items[tabControl.SelectedIndex + 1];
            }
            else
            {
                if (tabControl.SelectedIndex - 1 > -1)
                    tabControl.SelectedItem = tabControl.Items[tabControl.SelectedIndex - 1];
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is that scrolling with the mouse wheeling just changes the selected item in the upper TabControl. I want other TabControls to react to mouse wheeling too.

For example: if the cursor is in one of the upper TabControl items then I want them to react to mouse wheel scrolling, otherwise I want the lower TabControls items to react to the scrolling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner `TabControls` do react, but you barely notice as the outer tab switches as well, just add the line `e.Handled = true` at the very end of the handler and it should work as expected as the event will no longer [bubble](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx#routing_strategies) through to the outer handler.

*(By the way, as the event bubbles you can make this work only adding a handler to the event on the outer TabControl, you then need to change the logic on the handler a bit to get the "closest" TabControl  though)*